# Is this a known (valid?) projection?

Tags: projection, stereographic-projections

I've seen in several astrophysical articles the following projection used to transform (spherical) [equatorial coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system) $(\alpha,\delta)$ of a dataset, to rectangular $(x,y)$ coordinates:

$$
x = (\alpha - \alpha_0) * \cos(\delta)\\
y = (\delta - \delta_0)
$$

where $(\alpha_0,\delta_0)$ are the coordinates of the center of the dataset. The equations look very similar to the [Cylindrical Equidistant Projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalEquidistantProjection.html), but not quite.

Can the projection above be considered a cylindrical projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is shifted [Sinusoidal Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_projection).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant Hume2. Thank you!